# Flutter Firebase Realtime Access Denied Error

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ipad

I published a new release like 3 weeks ago. Everything was working fine until some iOS devices got stuck in the splash screen. When I debugged this issue on Mac I was getting this error:

> flutter: [firebase_database/permission-denied] Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

When I run the app in Android It's working fine. Also, this is happening in some devices like iPad or iPhone 13. Sometimes it happens to iPhone 14 but it starts running fine again automatically.

When I change the Wifi or mobile data the app starts running again in an iOS device. These are the permissions I am using in real-time database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write" : true,
  }
}
```

If there was a problem or issue in my app code then we should have encountered this problem just after publishing the app.

- I have checked the permissions in firebase and they are also fine.
- This is only happening in some iOS devices.
- I have upgraded the flutter version to 3.16.0 and also upgraded all the packages too including firebaseCore etc.

Comment: have you managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

```
you should try this once ,you might want to restrict access to authenticated users only:


{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me